# Is EndDate higher, or later than StartDate?

Tags: writing-style, programming, technical

In technical documentation, where you have two variables, StartDate and EndDate, how do you say that the EndDate must come after StartDate? Do you use the **lower-higher** or **sooner-later** comparison? Or is there a more intuitive and understandable way?

Comment: Uh, "the EndDate must be after the StartDate".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

References to dates are prevalent in computing. Besides building date validations in code, the working of a date field must be correctly referenced in system messages. It is always better to use descriptive statements (earlier/later) rather than quantifying it (lower/higher).

Use ***later*** to indicate that event is happening subsequent to a reference date (date subsequent to which it is possible/not possible to do something)

***Example***:

> The EndDate of the promotion must be **later** than the StartDate.
>
> You cannot enter an EndDate **later** than 31 December, 2020.

In case, you wish to indicate an event happening prior to  a reference date, use ***earlier***

> The StartDate of the scheduler must be **earlier** than the EndDate.
>
> The Coupon Code must not be active any **earlier** than Dec 24,2016.

*Reference*:  A technical documentation guideline developed by my Project!

See related [EL&U question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112257/above-or-later-when-referencing-a-range-of-versions-of-software) dealing with software version numbers.