# "Since Version x.y.z" or "Version x.y.z or later"?

Tags: word-choice, range-inclusion

Which one is correct when referring to a feature that has been implemented in a version x.y.z and is still available until the latest versions?

I have found this [link](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112257/above-or-later-when-referencing-a-range-of-versions-of-software) about "Version x.y.z or later"

But I have also seen "Deselect text. Since 5.1" being used [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeysequence.html)

Which one would be correct or at least the most common?

Comment: I've found the 'Deselect text. Since 5.1' entry, but can't decide immediately what the 5.1 is a version of. I find this unusual (I'd expect 'Since version 5.1' anyway), and I'd think that '[version 5.1 and later]' would be far more common. But 'which one is correct?' suggests strongly that one is forbidden. I doubt that there is a rule being broken here, unless we invoke 'always use the most idiomatic choice'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, thanks for your answer. So you believe that "Version 5.1 and later" would be the most idiomatic choice?

Comment: There are some expressions where it's not clear if version 5.1 is included ("following version 5.1", "after version 5.1") but both of these seem inclusive.

Comment: .............Yes.

Comment: What do you mean by *until* in *still available until the latest versions*? Do you mean that the feature is still available in the current version?

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct and commonly used. So you can safely use them. [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=version%20*%20or%20later%2Csince%20version%20*&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) clearly shows that the usages of these two formulas are intertwined:

[image]

If it helps, ***version x or later*** was most common in the 90s.

Answer (score 0):

The former answer is about referring to version numbers in an article about a piece of software. The latter example comes from a table in an API reference and refers to the version of the library being documented.

In the latter case, a more abbreviated style is appropriate. The readers (Qt programmers) can be expected to tell that it is a version number, that it is a version of Qt more specifically, and that it refers to an API not implemented in prior versions of the software.